How to make stop/contunie task in Airflow?
I'm trying to make Airflow dag to update database.
If I get no mistakes while get data from API I need to insert data to database.
If there's any errors - I need send errors messages.
So I need add check length of errors dict.
Actually I need make transform data then there's no errors before insert data to database, but I think there's no need to add this code to question.
How to make stop/continue tasks with using decorators?
Continue/stop logic:
if len(errors) == 0:
*insert table to database
else:
*send errors text to telegram
P. S. I make dict with table, cause I actually get from API few tables.
There's my code.
import pandas as pd
import time
import clickhouse_connect
import api_library

from airflow.decorators import dag, task

default_args = {
    'owner': 'owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 06, 20)
}

schedule_interval = '*/15 * * * *'

connect = clickhouse_connect.get_client(
    host = '*.*.*.*'
    , port = 8443
    , database = 'database'
    , username = 'admin'
    , password = 'password'
    )

bearer_key = '***'
user_key = '***'

def get_data_or_raise_error_with_retry(func, max_tries=10, **args):
    for _ in range(max_tries):
        try:
            # add sleep to avoid API break
            time.sleep(0.3)
            if len(args) == 0:
                return func()
            else:
                return func(**args)
        # I get error text instead pd.Dataframe
        except Exception as e:
            return e

def make_dict_api_tables(tables: list):
    error_text = 'Error in table {}.\nCheck function.{}.'
    # dict with functions I using to get tables
    tables = {
        'stores': {
            'text': 'stores' # table name
            , 'function': 'get_table' # fucntion to get data from API
            , 'result': tables[0]  # result with pd.Dataframe or tuple in some cases or error text
        }
    }
    tables_from_api = {}
    tables_from_api['stores'] = {
                'result': tables['stores']['result']
                , 'error_text': error_text.format(tables['stores']['text'], tables['stores']['function'])
            }
    return tables_from_api

def make_dict_with_errors(tables_dict: dict):
    messages_with_transform_errors = {}
    for key in tables_dict.keys():
        if type(tables_dict[key]['result']) not in [pd.DataFrame, tuple]: # if result not pd.Dataframe or tuple it's error
            # add error text to dict
            messages_with_transform_errors[key] = tables_dict[key]['error_text']
    return messages_with_transform_errors


@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=schedule_interval, catchup=False, concurrency=4)
def dag_update_database():
    @task
    def connect_to_api(bearer_key: str, user_key: str):
        # connecting to API
        api = api_library(bearer_key, user_key)
        return api
    
    @task
    def get_table_from_api(api, tries: int):
        # get table, result id pd.Dataframe
        result_from_salons_api = get_data_or_raise_error_with_retry(api.get_table, tries)
        return list(result_from_salons_api)


    @task
    def make_dict_with_tables_and_errors(table: list):
        # make dict with table
        tables_dict = make_dict_api_tables(table)
        # make dict with errors, dict will be empty if there's no errors
        errors = make_dict_with_errors(tables_dict)
        return tables_dict, errors


I believe you may benefit from using BranchPythonOperator. A bit of general reference - https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/airflow-branch-operator#taskbranch-branchpythonoperator. In short, the idea is simple a straightforward - add IF/else logic which depends on the condition to decide how to proceed based on the upstream XCOM result
In code, it might look like this:
import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(
    dag_id="validate_dag",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 20),
    default_args={
        "owner": "owner",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "retries": 2,
        "retry_delay": datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    schedule_interval="*/15 * * * *",
    catchup=False,
)
def database_update_r():

    @task
    def get_table_from_api():
        # get table, result id pd.Dataframe
        result_from_salons_api = [{"id": 1, "name": "store1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "store2"}]
        return result_from_salons_api

    @task
    def make_dict_with_tables_and_errors(table: list) -> dict[str, dict]:
        # make dict with table
        tables_dict = {"table": "table_content"}
        # make dict with errors, dict will be empty if there's no errors
        # NOTE: case #1
        # errors = {"error": "error"}
        # NOTE: case #2
        errors = {}
        return {"tables_output": tables_dict, "errors_output": errors}

    @task.branch
    def validate_on_errors(errors: dict):
        if errors:
            return "send_error"
        else:
            return "write_to_database"

    @task
    def send_error():
        # Task to send an error to telegram
        pass

    @task
    def write_to_database():
        # update database
        pass

    validate_on_errors(make_dict_with_tables_and_errors(get_table_from_api())["errors_output"]) >> [
        send_error(),
        write_to_database(),
    ]


database_update_r()

As a result, one of the tasks after BranchOperator will be skipped 
